# My iPhone won't shut down

Tags: iphone

what can I do to access idle mode of my iPhone 4s or shut down the phone? It has suddenly stopped accepting these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that the sleep/wake (top-most) button is not functioning/responding?  If so, you can access [Assistive Touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5587) in the iOS settings to give yourself a touchscreen method of mimicking many of the iPhone's hardware buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring it with iTunes. If it is a software bug in the OS of your iPhone it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter DYU mode by pressing the power button and home button simultaneously until it turns off.

You can also restore your phone by connecting it to iTunes and restore it.